# Laravel: Trying to push url strings to array in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a field in my AppSetup table called `reference_images` that is added as follows in the migration: `$table->json('reference_images')->nullable();` and casted as an array in the AppSetup model.  I have a method that adds image urls to the database.  If it's for the `reference_image` field, I am trying to push it to the array but I keep getting an "Array to String conversion" error in Laravel.

```
   public function addImagesToAppSetup($imageType=null, $image=null)
    {
        $appSetup = AppSetup::where('store', '=', id())->first();

        if ($image) {
            if ($imageType == "reference_images") {
                $originalArray = $appSetup->$imageType;
                $originalArray[] = $image;
                $appSetup->$imageType = array_values(array_unique($originalArray));
            } else {
                $appSetup->$imageType = $image;
            }
        }

        $appSetup->save();

        return response()->json(['status' => 1, 'data' => $appSetup]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since reference_images is of type json, doing array_values(array_unique($originalArray)); is still an Array. You will have to convert it to json.

e.g. using **collect()->json()** [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-tojson)

```
$appSetup->$imageType = collect($originalArray)->unique()->values()->toJson();
```